# SQL sum values of duplicate rows into the first one (or last one)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sum, duplicates

I want to merge the duplicated rows (with same doctype, docnum and item) and sum the value of their 'qtd' column to the first one or the last one. Then delete the duplicate rows keeping just the one that caries the total value. (The line number is not important after deleting it can allow not sequential numbers)

Actually I only have the query to detect the duplicated rows, I need the query to merge the value and to delete the duplicated rows that remain after the merge.

PS: This is a big table so the doctype, docnum and item cannot be expressed in the query like this... where doctype='stket' and docum='1' and item='4506' they must be found "automatically"

Table: docs (initial with the duplicated rows)

```
      doctype  docnum  line    item      qtd
       STKET     1       1   **4506**   10.00
       STKET     1       2     3860     27.00
       STKET     1       3   **4506**    4.00
       STKET     2       1     3860      7.00
       STKET     3       1   **4048**    2.00
       STKET     3       2   **4048**    5.00
       STKET     3       3     4876     11.00
       STKET     4       1     3860      1.00
```

Table: docs (expected result after sum)

```
      doctype  docnum  line    item      qtd
       STKET     1       1     4506   **14.00**
       STKET     1       2     3860     27.00
       STKET     1       3     4506      4.00
       STKET     2       1     3860      7.00
       STKET     3       1     4048    **7.00**
       STKET     3       2     4048      5.00
       STKET     3       3     4876     11.00
       STKET     4       1     3860      1.00
```

Table: docs (expected result after deleting duplicated - in this case not the first!)

```
      doctype  docnum  line    item      qtd
       STKET     1       1     4506   **14.00**
       STKET     1       2     3860     27.00
       STKET     2       1     3860      7.00
       STKET     3       1     4048    **7.00**
       STKET     3       3     4876     11.00
       STKET     4       1     3860      1.00
```

**[later edit] - from "answer"**

After the ZLK query I keep the table docs like this:

```
  doctype  docnum  line    item      qtd
   STKET     1       1     4506   **10.00**
   STKET     1       2     3860     27.00
   STKET     2       1     3860      7.00
   STKET     3       1     4048    **2.00**
   STKET     3       3     4876     11.00
   STKET     4       1     3860      1.00
```

It finds the duplicates and deletes but doesn't sum the 'qtd' value of the deleted rows

Comment: Why would the line become 0 and/or how is the line determined?

Comment: Sorry it was copy\paste error, i will edit the post, thanks! The line is auto (sequential) but it works fine in case of deleting some row and the numbers doesn't stay sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming all you want is a basic update statement then delete statement.

```
UPDATE docs SET qtd = updateqtd
FROM docs d
JOIN (SELECT doctype, docnum, item, MIN(line) line, SUM(qtd) updateqtd
FROM docs
GROUP BY doctype, docnum, item) a ON a.doctype = d.doctype AND a.docnum = d.docnum AND a.item = d.item AND a.line = d.line;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doctype, docnum, item ORDER BY line) RN
    FROM docs)
DELETE CTE WHERE RN <> 1
```

This updates the lowest line number then deletes any that aren't the lowest line number.

Comment: I will test it today. Thanks

Comment: Hi friend, sorry for the late response, I was testing your query and it works detecting the duplicate rows and keeping only one row (deleting all others), but it doesn't sum the 'qtd' before deleting

Comment: I have tested again your query and it works great! Thank you @ZLK